# Would I be allowed to post links to services that bypass paywalls?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, external-sources, piracy

Every now and then, mainly on sites like Skeptics, I come across a Stack Exchange post that links to a paywalled article. This isn't great, because even if the post is quoting the linked material like it's supposed to, the original source is still inaccessible to most visitors.

Recently, I discovered a service called [12ft Ladder](https://12ft.io/) that is able to bypass these paywalls, and then provides you a link to the un-paywalled article. It's occurred to me that I could replace any links to paywalled articles I find here on SE with 12ft Ladder links, or if I ever find a paywalled source while researching an answer, I can use 12ft Ladder to make it accessible to all when I write the answer.

However, I know SE does not condone piracy, and I'm conscious that bypassing a paywall might fall on the wrong side of that line. So I figured it'd be best to ask: **would I be allowed to post links to articles whose paywalls have been bypassed in this fashion?** Or is this forbidden under the "no piracy" rules?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the individual sites has a meta discussion with an official response... now I just need to remember is which site that was.

Comment: I might have technically done this with an answer I wrote recently... it linked to a New York Times article and pulled a quote, but I opted to use a Wayback Machine archived link in case they changed the wording later. However, that *does* have the effect of bypassing NYT's paywall.

Comment: @bobble *note to self*: next time, use `curl https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/20/world/europe/ukraine-biden-eu.html -O` when hit by paywall ...

Comment: I've used some complicated techniques to get around blocking. For example, I've backed up Google's cached version of a site on Archive.org (not sure they still allow this, maybe another archive site would). But neither of those are piracy sites at least. What about that?

Comment: @Catija Maybe this? [Links to copyright material](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5196)

Comment: Regardless of whether it's allowed, perhaps one downside of doing this is that you may end up with more dead links once the service is taken down. For that alone, I wouldn't exactly encourage it. Just quote the relevant parts with attribution to these sites, and it will be there as long as the site exists.

Comment: JNat found it for me. https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/whats-our-policy-on-sci-hub-links#comment6475_1618

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Indeed. I can see a case for adding an additional link, but not for replacing it up front.